# NoMethodError in UserController#register undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

Trying to learn ruby on rails following Michael Hartl's tutorial, when I try to go to the registration page in the book I get this:

> NoMethodError in UserController#register
>   undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass

here is the code from the user_controller.rb file:

```
   class UserController < ApplicationController
    def index
     @title = "RailsSpace User Hub"
     end

     def register
     @title = "Register"
     if request.post? and params[:user]
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    end
    if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "User #{@user.screen_name} created!"
    redirect_to :action => "index"
   end
  end

  private

  def user_params
  # Add the user attributes that you sent with post (form) to the permit 
   method.
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :screen_name)
  end
end
```

It's complaining about line 11 where it says: `if @user.save` I'm just following the tutorial I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Try to understand what the error message is saying.  You're trying to call `.save` on `@user` but where you are calling it, `@user` may not be defined.  The problem is you can't call `.save` on a nil object so it throws `NoMethodError`.

You're logic is incorrect so you must first make sure `@user` is instantiating a new `User` instance. It should be more like this:

```
def register
  @title = "Register"
  if request.post? && params[:user]
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "User #{@user.screen_name} created!"
      redirect_to :action => "index"
    else
      # handle erorrs here
      flash[:alert] = "Please fix errors: #{@user.errors.full_messages.inspect}"
      redirect_to :back #this may need to change depending, just an example.
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`NoMethodError in UserController#register undefined method 'save' for nil:NilClass`

The error is thrown because you are calling `save` on a `nil`; and it is because `nil` object does not have this method. the `save` is a instance method belonging to `ActiveRecord::Base` class.

The reason `@user` is nil is because `@user` is an instance variable in the `UserController` class which you have not given it any value. Any variable starting with `@` inside a class is an instance variable in Ruby.

To solve this problem, you should set a value to `@user`, and in this case it should be a `User` instance. You can either create a new user object by doing `@user = User.new(user_params)` or you fetch a record from the Database by doing `@user = User.find(<some_id>)`